# In Blender 2.92, I can't see the bloom effect like in the previous versions. Is there any settings to change that?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In Blender 2.92 while using eevee render engine I still can't see the bloom effect, even when it is turned on. Is there any change in settings should I do, or it's a bug in that?

Comment: It should work like before. Make sure you're using a bright material and that you're in mat preview or rendered mode

Answer (score 0):

Activate bloom effect
Go to the material section and click over the surface option and select Emission.
Than you can change the strength on it.
Go to render mode and you can see your bloom effect.

Comment: Best tutorial for bloom effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTFj9B6eFgk&list=PLBPZVsAXSH9HplNkY7DLJI-WEO6_27-zS&index=19